# Create a container with Golang on MacOS - syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS not working

Tags: go, containers, system-calls

Learning how to implement containers on Golang, using MacOS Terminal,
I'm trying to implement the following code as promoted on Docker:

```
unc main() {
    switch os.Args[1] {
    case "run":
        run()
    default:
        panic("Bad Command")
    }
}

func run() {
    fmt.Printf("Running %v \n", os.Args[2:])
    cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[2], os.Args[3:]...)
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Cloneflags: syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS,
    }
    cmd.Run()
}
```

However it seems that `syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS` works only with Linux.
How could I implement this on Mac ?

Comment: System calls are the interface to the kernel, and macOS, although it has many similarities with Unix (from FreeBSD and Mach), is not Linux. This is why you cannot expect the code to work. If I understand your goals correctly, I suggest to simply start a Linux VM on macOS and work in the VM.

Comment: Your reply confirms what I suspected. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a macos at hand, but if you're running into a similar problem on linx (ubuntu), first check if you are running your `go run .` as root.

If you are not, you will need an extra flag (`syscall.CLONE_NEWUSER`) passed into `SysProcAttr`:

```
func run() {
  fmt.Printf("Running %v \n", os.Args[2:])
  cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[2], os.Args[3:]...)
  cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
  cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
  cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
  cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
    Cloneflags: syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS | syscall.CLONE_NEWUSER,
}
cmd.Run()
```

What I think happens here is that without the `syscall.NEWUSER` flag, you will try to clone the current process as root, which you do not have permission to do so.

By the way OPs snippet is taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fi7uSYlOdc (in which all commands are run as the root user).

Comment: Thanks man, i faced the same issue on ubuntu and it worked by adding the NEWUSER flag

Answer (score 2):

thanks for @guites answer it worked with me. but adding the extra flag may be an unneeded workaround.

to solve this without adding the `CLONE_NEWUSER` flag you need to run your script as root. but buy default `go` executable run as non-root so you will need to build your script first and then run it with sudo.

```bash
go build main.go
sudo ./main
```

That what worked for me.